# Convergence of Sequence $a_n=1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7}+\ldots+\frac{1}{3n-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Apply Cauchy's principle of convergence to prove that the sequence $\langle a_n\rangle$ defined by $$a_n=1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7}+\ldots+\frac{1}{3n-2}$$ is not convergent

My attempt :

consider, 
\begin{align*}
 |a_{2m}-a_{m}|&=|1+1/4+1/7+\ldots+\frac{1}{3m-2}+\frac{1}{3m+1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{6m-2}\\
&-(1+1/4+1/7+\ldots+\frac{1}{3m-2})| \\ 
 &=|\frac{1}{3m+1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{6m-2}|\end{align*}

What do i do next ? i get confused after this step

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{1}{3n}<\dfrac{1}{3n-2}$, now use the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: You could probably use the divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Directly from your current position: hint 1: you can remove the absolute value; hint 2: bound below the sum by smallest term.

Comment: i basically need to show that the series will be greater than an $\epsilon$ , so how do i *think* further ?

Answer (score 4):

for $m>1$$$|\frac{1}{3m+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{6m-2}| > m\times\frac{1}{6m-2} \nrightarrow 0 $$

Comment: Wait you want the non-strict inequality otherwise it would be wrong for $m=1$..

Comment: i can add `for $m>1$' if you like...

Comment: For $m>1$ you mean...

Comment: And what's wrong with using $\ge$??

Comment: this is only detail anyway.

Comment: Yes here small indices don't matter but it pays to be careful sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{3k-2}>\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{3k}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}.$$

Now, since $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\to\infty$, when $n\to\infty$, we have
$$a_n\to\infty,\ \mbox{when}\ n\to\infty.$$

Comment: but we are not using cauchy's theorem here. ?

Comment: Yes of course, you only have to prove that the Harmonic Sequence is not Cauchy. What they did for you is to give you a lower bound, now it's your duty to finish it all.